# How can i add select2 to dynamically added dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to add multiple dropdowns[] dynamically and also want to get select2 as the dropdown list will be much bigger in length. I tried the following code but it's not working as expected. Like select2 class is getting added in the output dropdown but the functionality is not working so please help me to get it done,

thanks in advance

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12 add_more">
    <label for="">Select Video</label>
    <select class="form-control select2" name="video_id[]" required>
        <option value="">Select Video</option>
        <?php $pdo = Database::connect();$sql = "SELECT * FROM video ORDER BY video_id DESC";foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $data_video) {?>
        <option value="<?php echo $data_video['video_id']; ?>">
            <?php echo $data_video['video_id']; echo " - "; echo $data_video['video_title']; ?>
        </option><?php } ?>
    </select>
    <br>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var max_fields = 100; //Maximum allowed input fields 
        var wrapper = $(".add_more"); //Input fields wrapper
        var add_button = $(".add_fields"); //Add button class or ID
        var x = 1; //Initial input field is set to 1

        //When user click on add input button
        $(add_button).click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            //Check maximum allowed input fields
            if (x < max_fields) {
                x++; //input field increment
                //add input field
                $(wrapper).append(
                    '<div class="col-md-12" style="padding:0"><select class="form-control select2" name="video_id[]" required><option value="">Select Video</option><?php $pdo = Database::connect();$sql = "SELECT * FROM video ORDER BY video_id DESC";foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $data_video) {?><option value="<?php echo $data_video['
                    video_id ']; ?>"><?php echo $data_video['
                    video_id ']; echo " - "; echo $data_video['
                    video_title ']; ?></option><?php } ?></select><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'
                );
            }
        });

        //when user click on remove button
        $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('div').remove(); //remove inout field
            x--; //inout field decrement
        })

        $('.select2').select2({
            placeholder: "Select video Title",
            allowClear: true
        });

        $('body').on('DOMNodeInserted', 'select', function () {
            $(this).select2();
        });


    });
</script>
```

Comment: what is PHP code is doing in javascript ?? it wont run.

Comment: @xdeepakv Why not? It's a .php page

Comment: But this will render from backend, will be the same always. Why not jqury append

Comment: Guys can you please help me for select2 in dynamic dropdowns